# Caps, tab and fn not working in bootcamp

Tags: keyboard, bootcamp, windows

I am using bootcamp regularly with Windows 10. Everything was working fine but now caps, tab and fn is not working, whereas left shift is working fine and also tilde. I have tried

1. SMC reset
2. Created new account for windows

But nothing seems to work. I see this seems to be running issue searching on web, however I find no proper solution. And its really frustrating.

Station: **Macbook Book Air, mid 2013. El Capitan**

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried using an external keyboard to see if the problem exists there too?

Comment: @Allan I don't have it at this moment

Comment: It would be a good test.  Also, you should indicate what Mac model and what version of macOS you are running.

Comment: @Allan definitely, updated my question, however I have not used OSX for sometime

Comment: Since you're not using macOS, it might be a good idea to run [Apple Hardware Test (AHT)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257) to see if it's a keyboard failure.  Hold the D key while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter connected.